# How does postgrey handle changing FQDNs?

Tags: greylisting, postfix

Let's say I receive emails from the following clients:

mail2.dx300.mail.net
mail4.dx121.mail.net
mail5.dx121.mail.net

Even though these are all from the same service (e.g. LinkedIn or MailChimp), postgrey sees them as entirely different clients. How can I configure postgrey to just look at the domain (mail.net), not the FQDN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason Postgrey sees them as different clients is simply because they are. Each is a Different server with a unique ip-address and hostname.

Unless you add them to a whitelist first  they each have to prove they behave like a proper smtp daemon.

But if they all are trusted clients you do not have to individually add them to the whitelist, you have the following options:

```
# Whitelist the whole domain
example.com
mail.net

# Use Regular Expressions 
/^mail[0-9].dx[0-9]{3}.mail.net$/

# Use CIDR IP Addresses:
10.9.8.0/24
```

Comment: Thanks! And there's no way to whitelist a sender email address, correct? (vs mail client IP/host)

Comment: No, because an email address is not the sending party but a SMTP server is.

Comment: Sender email address is part of the triplet though. The greylist triplet consists of mail client / sender email / recipient email. It's too bad it's not possible to whitelist based on sender email. Thanks for the answer!